# how to convert web project to a web application

Tags: web, visual-studio-2012, project

In Visual Studio 2010 there used to be an option to where you right-click on a project and convert it to a web application.
I want to do that and I cant seem to find that option to convert a web project to a web application with visual studio 2012

Comment: You mean to convert from a web site to a web application project?

Comment: Yes, That is what I meant!

Comment: Have you been able to find the solution to this?
even me i am looking for this exact solution